# What is the equation for condition of obtaining a bright spot in a wedge shaped film?

Tags: interference

I want to know if the condition for obtaining a bright spot in a wedge shaped film is

$2 \mu t\cos(r+\theta)=(n+\frac{1}{2})λ$

or

$2 \mu t \cos(r+\theta)=(2n-1)λ/2$ .

$t$ = thickness
$r$ = angle of refraction
$\theta$ = angle of inclination
$n$ = 0,1,2....

Comment: These are the same equation to within the choice of starting $n$ at 0 or 1.

Comment: You mean that if I start n from 0, I'll have to use the first equation? But what if n is already given and I have to find the other missing value?

Comment: @dmckee Ok thanks.I understood. 
So if the value is already given I can use either of the equations.
How can I mark your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If starting n at 0 use the first equation.
If starting n at 1 use the second equation.